# How to export data from SQL Server table to Excel file

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have a table in a SQL Server database. I want to send the Excel sheet via Email attachment. I have a code to send the mail but i need to generate an excel sheet of a given table.

Comment: urly guy to vote down, this is a real experience, please careful to vote down one question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you have a look at this link from Mr. P Dave
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/11/20/sql-server-how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-to-excel-or-any-other-format/

Comment: thanx for your quick response. This is useful for me.